# How to execute shell commands silently?

Tags: external-command

`:!<command>` can be used to execute a command in the shell. But this "takes over" my terminal and fills it with `stdout` of that particular command.

How do I execute a command in the background that only notifies me on a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Would you be willing to use the +python interface, or one of the other language interfaces?

Comment: @joeytwiddle Yes

Answer (score 77):

`:silent exec "!command"`

Note that your vim session will still be occupied while your command is executing. This is due to Vim's synchronous nature. You can still get back to your shell by pressing CTRL+z (to send Vim to the background) and then resume vim with the command `fg` as usual.

To do things asynchronously, take a look at Tim Pope's plugin [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) or the project NeoVim which has native support for asynchronous command execution, which you can easily leverage using the plugin NeoMake. The latest version of Vim also has support for asynchronous tasks.

See [:h :silent](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Asilent)

Comment: This is also the first thing that I tried when I saw the question :-) But if you use a command that outputs to stdout (or stderr), it will "clobber" your main Vim window (try `:silent !ls`) ... It also doesn't give proper output on a non-0 exit code... So I'm afraid it's a bit more involved than just using `:silent`...

Comment: Oh, sorry. Added some notes about asynchronous execution while you wrote your comment. Don't know how to address the exit status issue. You might want to try in #vim on Freenode.

Comment: I also want to note that neither `:silent exec "!ls"` nor `:silent !ls` show any output at all on my version of Vim, 7.4 with patches 1-213.

Comment: Hm, here's what I get after `:silent !ls`:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/1XvS6.png ... I need to press `^L` to fix it again ...

Comment: vim-dispatch certainly looks like a solution to the given problem.

Comment: `:silent` sometimes doesn't work in Neovim, for reasons that don't seem understood right now: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3196 (UPDATE: ah, but this might just be the same 'stdout clobbers the Vim window' issue that @Carpetsmoker already described above)

Comment: May I suggest `:silent exec "!command&"`?

Answer (score 43):

To execute a command without triggering the Enter message, like:

> Press ENTER or type command to continue

try the following simple example:

```
:silent !echo Hello
```

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (or `:redraw!`) to refresh the screen when back to Vim.

To avoid need for refresh, you can define your own custom command, like:

```
:command! -nargs=1 Silent execute ':silent !'.<q-args> | execute ':redraw!'
```

Now, you can use the new Vim command to run a shell command (note: without *!* and with capital *S*):

```
:Silent ps
```

Source: [Avoiding the "Hit ENTER to continue" prompts](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoiding_the_%22Hit_ENTER_to_continue%22_prompts) at the Vim Wikia site

Comment: How do you get notified on a non-zero exit code?

Comment: Not a solution to the non-zero exit code, but to add to this, this Silent command allows commands like `:Silent ctags -R . > /dev/null &` to run in the background. Sending stdout to /dev/null prevents output from appearing in the vim buffer.

Answer (score 12):

## A quick and dirty solution (in pure Vimscript)

This can start a process in the background:

```
:!slow_command_here > /tmp/output 2>&1 &
```

But Vim needs a way to find out when the process has completed, and how, so let's use a marker file:

```
:!(rm -f /tmp/finished; slow_command_here > /tmp/output 2>&1; echo "$?" > /tmp/finished) &
```

Now we can ask Vim to check every so often whether the process has completed:

```
:augroup WaitForCompletion
:autocmd!
:autocmd CursorHold * if filereadable('/tmp/finished') | exec "augroup WaitForCompletion" | exec "au!" | exec "augroup END" | echo "Process completed with exit code ".readfile('/tmp/finished')[0] | end
:augroup END
```

Hey it's not pretty, but it sort-of works!

### Disadvantages

Unfortunately the autocmd above won't trigger until you move the cursor.  And if you wanted to run more than one background process at a time, you would need to add unique IDs to those files, and to the autocmd group name.

So if you can handle an extra dependency, you might be better off using a tried-and-tested solution like the vim-dispatch plugin mentioned in another answer.

### Displaying output

If you want to see the **output** of the process, rather than just the **exit code**, then replace the final `echo` above with:

```
silent botright pedit /tmp/output
```

That would open the preview window.  To use the quickfix error list instead:

```
silent cget /tmp/output | copen
```

The quickfix list lets you easily navigate to errors using `:cnext`. However `copen` moves your cursor into the quickfix window when it opens, which will probably be surprising/annoying.

(A workaround for that would be to open the QF window with `:copen` when initially starting the process, so you will *not* need to call it at the end.)

Comment: This is the only answer here that actually answers the question: *" execute a command in the background that only notifies me on a non-zero exit code"* ... I have no idea why the other answers even have upvotes at all...

Comment: I believe they have upvotes because they perfectly answer the *title* of the question, which is what brings visitors to this page. "How to execute shell commands silently?" A common SE phenomenon! Visitors are grateful, but perhaps not disciplined.

Comment: In an ideal world, we would probably have two separate questions: "How to execute shell commands silently?" and "How to execute shell commands in the background?" so that googlers can find what they are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

### Running a command in the background

I was running a command that blocked for a bit, and I didn't really care about the output. This can be taken care of by starting the process attached not to the terminal/emulator but rather to the system and redirecting all output to /dev/null. For example:

```
:silent exec "!(espeak 'speaking in background'&) > /dev/null"
```

the `(...&)` runs it in the background and `> /dev/null` redirects all output to `/dev/null` (nothing).

The parenthesis trap the output into a subshell (or something like that), but it does have the side-effect of not being attached to the current shell (not a big deal).

### Running a command silently in the background with mapping

I just realized that if you *are*, in fact, mapping it, you can do something like

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>e :!$(espeak 'speaking in the background'&) > /dev/null
```

The above will display nothing in the command bar and will, additionally, not display anything in the terminal outside of vim. It will be mapped to <kbd>`<leader>`</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd>, which is <kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> by default.

### Running a command, capturing its output, displaying its contents

(Another edit - and maybe the neatest one). This one will *display* the *output* of a command if you so choose:

---

INSIDE A NEW TAB:

```
silent exec "!(echo 'hello. I'm a process! :)') > /tmp/vim_process" | :tabedit /tmp/vim_process
```

---

INSIDE A VERTICAL SPLIT:

```
silent exec "!(echo 'hello. I'm a process :)') > /tmp/vim_process" | :vs /tmp/vim_process
```

---

INSIDE A HORIZONTAL SPLIT:

```
silent exec "!(echo 'hello. I'm a process :)') > /tmp/vim_process" | :sp /tmp/vim_process
```

... do whatever you want

Answer (score 9):

If you don't care about exit code, you can go with this:

```
:call system('/usr/bin/zathura using-docker.pdf &')
```

Comment: If you care about the exit code, the `v:shell_error` variable will tell you

Comment: To me, this answer is underrated and should probably be the accepted one.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for! All other combinations of `:!cmd`, `:silent! !cmd`, and `exec('!cmd')` all either paused till you pressed enter, flashed the screen, or forced you to call `:redraw!`. This is the only one that worked completely silently.

Answer (score 8):

Vim 8 introduced jobs support. One can run external command in the background without relying on plugins. For example, to run a markdown server ([markserv](https://github.com/markserv/markserv)) at current location and not block vim session:

```
:call job_start('markserv .')
```

This starts markserv process as a sub-process of current vim process. You can verify this with `pstree`.

See [job_start](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/channel.txt.html#job-start)

Comment: In Neovim, the function is called `jobstart` and it's the only way I was able to spawn an Android Emulator with cold start in the background. Good stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this suits your needs, (does not handle background processes as in `foo &`  – not sure if that is what you mean by *“in the background”*), but a custom command could be used as in:

```
fun! s:PraeceptumTacet(cmd)
    silent let f = systemlist(a:cmd)
    if v:shell_error
        echohl Error
        echom "ERROR #" . v:shell_error
        echohl WarningMsg
        for e in f
            echom e
        endfor
        echohl None
    endif
endfun

command! -nargs=+ PT call s:PraeceptumTacet(<q-args>)
```

Then use as e.g.:

```
:PT ls -l
:PT foobar
ERROR #127
/bin/bash: foobar: command not found
```

If you do not need / want the error message a simple  `system()` could suffice, then check for `v:shell_error` and report by e.g `echo Error!`.

From *help v:shell_error*:

```
                                        v:shell_error shell_error-variable
v:shell_error   Result of the last shell command.  When non-zero, the last
                shell command had an error.  When zero, there was no problem.
                This only works when the shell returns the error code to Vim.
                The value -1 is often used when the command could not be
                executed.  Read-only.
                Example: >
    :!mv foo bar
    :if v:shell_error
    :  echo 'could not rename "foo" to "bar"!'
    :endif
                "shell_error" also works, for backwards compatibility.
```

Comment: This isn't really running it in the background; you still need to wait for it to finish.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Yes, thus my comment *“… does not handle background processes as in `foo &` …”*. From the Q text as a whole I interpreted it as being either or. Either *“Execute as external command AKA background”* or *“Execute as external command _and_ as background process.”*. I answered mainly based on the title of Q etc. – and added a comment on *“Not sure …”* – and left it to OP to clarify if either or.

Answer (score 4):

I use the following code:

```
command! -nargs=1 Silent call SilentExec(<q-args>)

function! SilentExec(cmd)
  let cmd = substitute(a:cmd, '^!', '', '')
  let cmd = substitute(cmd, '%', shellescape(expand('%')), '')
  call system(cmd)
endfunction
```

Now you can type the following

```
:Silent !your_command
```

This looks almost like Vim's built-in `silent !` command, except for the capital `S`. It even allows for an optional `!` to make it look even more similar. The call to `system()` makes the shell command truly silent: no screen flashes and no redraws.

(and if you ever need a status code, you can check the `v:shell_error` variable, see help for more info)

Answer (score 3):

The [AsyncRun](https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim) plugin if designed for this, it allows you to run shell commands in the background in Vim8/NeoVim and display the output in the quickfix window.

Just as a replacement of `!` command:

```
:AsyncRun ls -la /
```

You can also hide the output in quickfix window completely:

```
:AsyncRun -mode=3 ls -la /
```

When job finished, AsyncRun will notify you by passing an option `-post`:

```
:AsyncRun -post=some_vim_script   ls -la /
```

The vim script defined by `-post` will be executed after job finished.