# Run a python script without closing buffer

Tags: external-command

I have a script that writes output to a text file which I have open in a split side-by-side my code.

If I use `:! python %` it will close the window to display the terminal, show the script's terminal output and ask me to press enter to get back to my editor screen.

Since all I care about can be seen in the text file I already have open, I want to be able to just run the script and have no disruptions on screen. Alternatively, is it possible to have a 'mini-terminal' open as a split so that I can see the output of the script if need be?

Comment: You might have a look at vim-dispatch: https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch

Comment: I love [ConqueTerm](https://code.google.com/p/conque/)

Comment: [How to execute shell commands silently?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1942/how-to-execute-shell-commands-silently/1947?s=1|0.1919#1947) is also very similar (but doesn't cover the 'mini-terminal' part).

Answer (score 2):

For your situation, I believe you could do `:call system('python '.%)` to run the same thing without showing the output.

When I have a script that can write to stdout, I usually open a new window and do `:r !python #` to append the python output to the buffer directly.

Note that neither of these solutions are asynchronous-- vim will pause while the script is running. For async, you'd want to look at dispatch (or one of the underlying techniques it uses) or neovim.