# How do I search google from Vim?

Tags: external-command, bash

I would like to be able to search google from within any Vim file. A nice command might be `:goo` while in normal mode.

Then I type what I want to search and bam it opens my default browser with the search.

How would I do this?

Comment: I think you can have a look at https://github.com/szw/vim-g

Comment: I dunno, type then open browser, or open browser then type. Seems a bit pointless me. Plus if you type in the browser you get search completion. What's the use case?

Comment: The use case is not having to switch focus to browser, also being able to paste confusing code from any of the registers into the search. Sometimes system register is a little choppy and it would be and extra step to copy to that register. Plus come on -->"Googling from vim"<--

Comment: If you want to google from your text editor you should have a look at emacs ;-) More seriously, I understand that it is fun to see but IMO that's not an efficient way to use Vim.

Comment: You will switch focus, at least mentally, so using the "right" tool for what you want is a plus. I feel like "Googling from vim" is like "gdb from vim", it can be done, but it's not the purpose of each tool (aka vim is only a text editor, nothing more).

Comment: Well I have a couple of mappings to quickly copy stuff to the system clipboard. And I have an OS-level key binding to open Chrome. So it's dead easy to get stuff from vim into Chrome. The benefit of this is that you can use it with other applications, not just your web browser. It's a quick win and is composable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

Using a plugin:

- [vim-g](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4183)
- [gsearch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3551)
- [vim-quicklink](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-quicklink)

Or, if you prefer a lightweight solution, you can try the following:

```
function! GoogleSearch()
     let searchterm = getreg("g")
     silent! exec "silent! !firefox \"http://google.com/search?q=" . searchterm . "\" &"
endfunction
vnoremap <F6> "gy<Esc>:call GoogleSearch()<CR>
```

([source](https://superuser.com/a/212060/367359))

Using the [vim-shell](https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell) plugin you can rewrite this to:

```
function! GoogleSearch()
     let searchterm = getreg("g")
     Open "http://google.com/search?q=" . searchterm . "\" &"
endfunction
vnoremap <F6> "gy<Esc>:call GoogleSearch()<CR>
```

You can also have a look at those links:

- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_the_web_for_text_selected_in_Vim
- https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/37ou4p/help_me_search_google_from_vim/
- http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Internet_search_for_the_current_word

And I highly recommend [this video by Drew Niel](https://vimeo.com/122615320).

Comment: The [`vim-shell` plugin](https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell) could be used to make your function to be OS/browser agnostic.

Comment: `"silent! !firefox \"http://google.com/search?q=" . searchterm . "\" &"` should be `"silent! !firefox \"http://google.com/search\\?q\\=" . searchterm . "\" &"`

Answer (score 2):

As others have  pointed out, Searching from Vim is not something one would want to do every time, but I do understand that there are some situations where you just want to search for a particular word in Vim. In those situations this plugin might be useful.

Mind you, this is something I wrote only for the purpose of searching for the word under the cursor, nothing more.

[Vim-Scour](https://github.com/durgaswaroop/vim-scour)

The Readme file has info about how to use this. And even if you don't want to use the plugin itself, look at the plugin file. Its really small and you will get an idea about how you can do system calls.

Comment: It's nice to see you are starting to write Vim plugins. I suggest you have a look at `:h :execute`, which let you insert variable name in your commands. This could simplify largely your `scour#Search` function.

Comment: I agree with @nobe4: your function could be one line actually: `execute "silent !" . g:scour_browser . " www." . g:scour_search_engine . ".com/search?q=<cword>"`. `execute` will execute the string provided as argument, in the string you simply concatenate the browser and search engine variables with `.` and you're good to go :-)

Comment: @statox Thanks for the suggestion. It was a while ago I wrote that. I was just learning Vim scripting then. Though I am still a beginner in scripting I haven't bothered to update the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
x-www-browser https://google.com
```

then you can do a search or if you want to open a link it would be like this

```
x-www-broswer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I'm not sure you addressed how to do this specifically in vim, though it looks as simple as doing `:! x-ww-browser ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap gy :silent execute "!google-chrome http://google.com/search?q=" . shellescape("<cWORD>") . " &"<CR>
vmap gy <Esc>:silent execute "!google-chrome http://google.com/search?q=" . shellescape("<C-r>*") . " &"<CR>
```

The first command allows you press `gy` to search for a word under your cursor. The second command allows you to visually search for a term, also using `gy` but in visual mode. Replace `google-chrome` with your browser command or use `vim-shell` as in the other answer.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

Providing a snippet to resolve url encoding.

```
" ref: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/1958/49235
" Call shell command silently then Ctrl+L (or :redraw!) to refresh the screen when back to Vim.
command! -nargs=1 Silent execute ':silent !'.<q-args> | execute ':redraw!'

" google search
nnoremap <silent> gG  :Silent open "http://google.com/search?q="<c-r>=<sid>encode_words(expand("<cword>"))<cr><cr>
vnoremap <silent> gG y:Silent open "http://google.com/search?q="<c-r>=<sid>encode_words(@")<cr><cr>

" https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42717/how-do-i-turn-a-string-into-url-encoded-string
" URL encode a string. ie. Percent-encode characters as necessary.
function! s:encode_words(text) abort
    " Replace `\n`, preserve `\`
    let words = substitute(a:text, '\n', ' ', 'g')
    let words = substitute(words, '\\', '\\\', 'g')

    let result = ""
    let characters = split(words, '.\zs')
    for character in characters
        if character == " "
            let result = result . "+"
        elseif s:needs_encode(character)
            let i = 0
            while i < strlen(character)
                let byte = strpart(character, i, 1)
                let decimal = char2nr(byte)
                " Avoiding command expansion
                let result = result . "\\%" . printf("%02x", decimal)
                let i += 1
            endwhile
        else
            let result = result . character
        endif
    endfor

    return result
endfunction

" Returns 1 if the given character should be percent-encoded in a URL encoded
" string.
function! s:needs_encode(character)
    let ascii_code = char2nr(a:character)
    if ascii_code >= 48 && ascii_code <= 57
        return 0
    elseif ascii_code >= 65 && ascii_code <= 90
        return 0
    elseif ascii_code >= 97 && ascii_code <= 122
        return 0
    elseif a:character == "-" || a:character == "_" || a:character == "." || a:character == "~"
        return 0
    endif

    return 1
endfunction
```