# How Do I Turn a String into URL Encoded String?

Tags: vimscript, encoding

I'm trying to turn a JSON format string into parsable URL encoded string.

Here's my process:

```
" Read the contents of the file separated into lines
let lines = join(getline(1, '$'), '\n')

" Assign an empty string for annotations
let annotations = ''

" Separate markup from content into a list
let contents = split(lines, '\v(\<[^<]*\>|[^<]+)\zs')

" Add contents into annotations in JSON format
for content in contents
  if match(content, '<[^>]*>') > -1
    let annotations .= '{"markup":'
  else
    let annotations .= '{"text":'
  endif

  let annotations .= ' "' . content . '"},'
endfor

" Generate the JSON output
let json_data = '{"annotation":' . annotations . '}'
```

This is how the output looks now:

```
"{\"annotation\":{\"text\": \"Style and grammer checker\"}}"
```

The desired output would be this:

```
%7B%22annotation%22%3A%5B%7B%22text%22%3A%22Style%20and%20grammer%20checker%22%7D%5D%7D
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. [Urlencode a multiline string in VIM, so it can be used to query a search engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76431955/urlencode-a-multiline-string-in-vim-so-it-can-be-used-to-query-a-search-engine) on SO seems to be about the same problem. In the comments, there are links to the existing answer as well as to other solutions.

Comment: Yup!  The link I provided in the answer is the first in the list.

Comment: I think in your previous question you said you weren't parsing HTML, but it sure looks like you might be. I strongly suggest you consider writing this program in another language, and using Vimscript only to coordinate sending text from the editor to it and receiving the results.

Comment: True. I misunderstood the definition of parsing. I had to look at the definition again. Sorry. I thought parsing was a more advance way of dealing with contents. It seemed like what I wanted to do was simpler than what parsing tools do. I've decided to parse the content in a Ruby script instead. Thanks for the advice. The code of my Vimscript looks better now.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://www.danielbigham.ca/cgi-bin/document.pl?mode=Display&DocumentID=1053) and it works fine.

```
" URL encode a string. ie. Percent-encode characters as necessary.
function! UrlEncode(string)

    let result = ""

    let characters = split(a:string, '.\zs')
    for character in characters
        if character == " "
            let result = result . "+"
        elseif CharacterRequiresUrlEncoding(character)
            let i = 0
            while i < strlen(character)
                let byte = strpart(character, i, 1)
                let decimal = char2nr(byte)
                let result = result . "%" . printf("%02x", decimal)
                let i += 1
            endwhile
        else
            let result = result . character
        endif
    endfor

    return result

endfunction

" Returns 1 if the given character should be percent-encoded in a URL encoded
" string.
function! CharacterRequiresUrlEncoding(character)

    let ascii_code = char2nr(a:character)
    if ascii_code >= 48 && ascii_code <= 57
        return 0
    elseif ascii_code >= 65 && ascii_code <= 90
        return 0
    elseif ascii_code >= 97 && ascii_code <= 122
        return 0
    elseif a:character == "-" || a:character == "_" || a:character == "." || a:character == "~"
        return 0
    endif

    return 1

endfunction
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18053)

Comment: Thanks! I just added it to the answer.