# How to echo a command but avoid the "hit enter" prompt

Tags: echo

I have found how to [silently](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/1942/9863) execute a command with `:silent`, but I actually would like to **echo** the command being executed, without getting into this "hit-enter" prompt. How to do it?

My example is a function for synctex forward search, put into my vimrc:

```
function! SyncTexForward()
    " use file path relative to current directory
    let execstr = "silent !zathura --synctex-forward ".line(".").":".col(".").":".@%." ".fnamemodify(@%, ":r") . ".pdf &"
    exec execstr
endfunction
```

Without `silent`, it would display the command + its output, that is one line with the pid, like this:

```
:!zathura --synctex-forward 612:1:myfile.tex myfile.pdf &
[1] 4648

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I tried temporarily changing `&cmdheight` to 2, but it has the same effect as `silent` (no echo at all)

Answer (score 1):

So my question was quite stupid actually. It sufficed to add:

```
echo execstr
```

just before

```
exec execstr
```

Now if I could also capture the shell stdout and display it too, it would also be nice.