# How do I run a shell command periodically and silently from within Vi?

Tags: repeated-commands

Before I came here, I went to [executing command from within Vim](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~pcs/apps/editors/vi/vi_unix.html) and learned it can be done using:

> :!command

Then I went to [executing it silently](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/1942/how-to-execute-shell-commands-silently) and figured how that I need to run:

> :silent exec "!command"

Now I want to do it periodically like every 5 seconds or so. Can anyone help me?

The requirement is that I need to generate tags on the go as I write the code using Ctags.

I'll prefer OG answers if possible over the Plugins and some other tools/utilities.

Comment: putting the command into bash file and running the bash file silently? Will that work?

Comment: you can make use of the timer functionality (see  `:h timer_start`)

Comment: If you decide to do this outside of Vim, then you may want to look at [`watch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watch_(Unix)). See `man watch`

Comment: Just out of interest, what is "OG" meant to stand for?

Comment: Old generation, Not in a disrespectful way but as in more experienced and one prefering the old ways to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ChristianBrabandt mentions in the comments, presuming you're using a reasonably recent version of Vim, you could do this with a timer.

In fact, you can virtually just copy-paste the example in from `:help timer-start`:

```
func MyHandler(timer)
  silent exec "!command"
endfunc
let timer = timer_start(500, 'MyHandler', {'repeat': -1})
```

I wouldn't recommend this though. I think you're better of using an [alternative method](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5cv5ge/how_do_you_manage_your_ctags/) such as:

- generate tags on file save by using an autocommand,
- generate the tags outside of Vim with something like `watch`, `inotify` or [git hooks](http://tbaggery.com/2011/08/08/effortless-ctags-with-git.html),
- use a plugin. I use [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags), but there are several others.

Comment: I made a change to my .vimrc by copying that into it for testing. It takes me out of vi everytime. Now I can't edit my .vimrc using vim LOL. GUIs Text Editor for the rescue. And I figured out just now that I may open other files using vim as well, so generating tags and scope file for that sounds so stupid to me, didn't think about that myself.

Comment: You could also have started vim with the command `vim -Nu NONE ~/.vimrc` to ignore your vimrc while you fixed it. If you want to persist with rolling your own Vimscript solution, I’d look into autocommands.

Comment: No, I don't persist to use my own script, I had it on high preference since sometimes plugins dont exactly match your need and time is wasted. I looked into your Alternative methods, gutentags seems fine as of now , I am still testing. Will let you know by the end of day, Indian Standard Time.